# How to have "Modified" ALWAYS available and visible in File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

From time to time, if I get into folder, filled with images or some folder from attached device, I have it displayed without `Modified` column. Also, `Modified`  is absent in `Sort by` menu.

Is it possible to set, that "Modified date-time" is an extremely important data for me (system administrator :) ) and to force Windows to ALWAYS provide this data?

I know I can manually add this column any time. But I don't want to do it again and again.